# NODE_ENV' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: javascript, node.js, server-side

I am learning NODE js and i have a server file that includes NODE_env as port configuration , the code works on a MAC but throws up an error on my windows. How do i solve this?

Answer (score 14):

Have you tried installing it globally or include it in your project's or your library's optional dependencies?

if not, try this:

install globally: 
`npm install -g win-node-env`

Or you may include it in your project's or your library's optional dependencies:
`npm install --save-optional win-node-env`

refer below link for more information
[npmjs win-node-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/win-node-env)

Comment: npm install --save-optional win-node-env works for me

Answer (score 2):

If you run into this problem in 2021, install `cross-env` as a dev dependency by running `npm i -D cross-env`.

Then, modify your command in the package.json file thus:
`cross-env NODE_ENV=development node my_script.js`

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to set NODE_ENV in windows? You can set it as a user or machine environment variable. You can also set it when you call the script in the command line:

```
NODE_ENV=development node my_script.js
```