# " 'env' is not recognized as an internal or external command, " in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, npm, next.js, environment-variables

I was working in a project which I cloned from a GitLab repo, while I was running it locally it gave me this error

```
npm run dev

> ideeza-web-app@1.0.0 dev
> env TAILWIND_MODE=watch next -p 3200

'env' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I was expecting it to run after installing dotnev,
I installed dotnev and did an " npm update " too, however still, it's not working.

Comment: That appears to be a command prompt (`cmd`) error message, not from Next. Does it work if you run `set TAILWIND_MODE=watch` and then on the next line `next -p 3200`?

Comment: can you tell me how to put next -p 3200 on the next line?

Comment: its showing like this on the scripts in package.json : "dev": "env TAILWIND_MODE=watch next -p 3200",

Answer (score 0):

Try installing cross-env with

```
npm install --save-dev cross-env
```

and then in package.json change env to cross-env, as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68983780/8890345). There's also the `win-node-env` module but I don't think it knows about that environment variable.

After changing that, the line in package.json should be:

```
"dev": "cross-env TAILWIND_MODE=watch next -p 3200",
```

If you need to handle signals in your program use `cross-env-shell` command (also provided by `cross-env` module) instead of `cross-env`.